# How to fully sync two branches in perforce

Tags: perforce

I want to overwrite all files in branch B with another branch A. The use case is:

- I branched B from A
- Made some changes on B
- Made other changes on A
- <strike>I want B to be exactly the same as A, all changes on B are discarded</strike>
- I want all files on B to be exactly the same as A, all additional changes on B are discarded (updated)

Is these a quick way to achieve this?
`p4 branch` would lead to a new branch C. And `p4 integrate` would keep the changes on B.

One possible way is, remove all files of B, and copy all files of A to B, and then run `p4 reconcile` on B. It's a little complicated. Anyone know a quick way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like you are looking for `p4 copy A/... B/...`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot @BryanPendleton

Answer (score 2):

'p4 copy' will copy files from one branch to another:

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r16.1/manuals/cmdref/p4_copy.html

The previous history of branch B will still remain.

If you wish for it to look as if branch B was always an exact copy of branch A, then you may wish to obliterate it and re-create it.

Note that 'p4 obliterate' completely removes data from Perforce, so should be used with care and backups should be taken before running it.

More information about this command is here:

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r16.1/manuals/cmdref/p4_obliterate.html

Hope this helps,
Jen.

Comment: Actually what I wish is all files on branch B to be exactly the same as files on branch A. Sorry it's not clearly described in my question. `p4 copy` match my requirement. Anyway, thanks for your mention of `p4 obliterate`.